# Old project doesn't recognise lambda expression

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have an old project that was using .net 4.5 which I have upgraded to .net 4.6.2. I am using visual studio 2017, so it should support lambda expressions, but when I try to run my project it always throws this error:

> Invalid token '=>' in class, struct, or interface member declaration

How can I get my project to compile using c# 6? I thought just upgrading the target framework was enough?

Comment: Could you please show us some code?

Comment: Lambda is C# 3 , right ? So it's for .Net 3.-3.5. It sould be good.

Comment: Could the syntax be invalid or Something like this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Adding the reference for Microsoft.Net.Compilers to the said project using Nuget (specific for 2.10 or above) to force compiler bindings to use 4.6+ features.

Invalid token class error usually appears when .Net Compilers are not correctly configured in Project.

`Install-Package Microsoft.Net.Compilers -Version 2.10.0`

Note: If you're using VS 2017, it should automatically do so.

Comment: I had migrated one of the projects running on .net 4.5 to .net 4.7 and was able to use the features such as Token lambdas without any issue. Note: I have been using VS 2015 and able to migrate & publish it successfully.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the *Advanced Build Settings* most likely

```
RightClick Project -> Properties -> Build -> Advanced build settings
```

Set the `Language Version` to your favorite or something appropriate

[image]

Comment: By default, the version was set to use lastest Major version, but when changing my version I got a new error.

Answer (score 0):

By changing the default language version, I started getting another error:

> Invalid option '7' for /langversion; must be ISO-1, ISO-2, Default or an integer in range 1 to 6

I investigated this and found some answers, which lead me to the correct answer.
The only thing I had to do was update the package

Microsoft.Net.Compilers

It was using version **1.3**, I upgraded to **2.10.0** and everything worked.