# Azure DevOps Invalid token '=>' in class, struct, or interface member declaration

Tags: azure, azure-devops, c#-7.0

Oh, the most annoying thing ever :( So I spent some time trying to get my old application to [compile using c# 7 and managed it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54232638/old-project-doesnt-recognise-lambda-expression/54232794?noredirect=1#comment95291423_54232794), now that is finally working I was ready to setup devops.

I created my pipeline as usual, but the first issue was when I pushed a build, it moaned about not supporting .net **4.7.2**. Awesome.
So I downgraded the project to **4.6.2** and then ran my pipeline again and now I get this:

> Invalid token '=>' in class, struct, or interface member declaration

I have checked the nuget restore in devops and it is using .net compilers 2.10.0.
I am at a loss. Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: some of our projects target c#7 and are built with pipelines with no issue. Did you target vs2017 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Agent pool may need to be `Hosted VS2017`.

As @NicoD mentioned, we also are building c# 7 projects with no issues by targeting this host.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For other users who have custom/hosted agents, you have to install this in server where agent runs:

- Be sure you have correct Build Tools for Visual Studio installed: [How can I install the VS2017 version of msbuild on a build server without installing the IDE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42696948/how-can-i-install-the-vs2017-version-of-msbuild-on-a-build-server-without-instal)
- And don't forget install this option too: [MS-Build 2017 "Microsoft.WebApplication.targets " is missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44061932/ms-build-2017-microsoft-webapplication-targets-is-missing)